# Jquery add only current selected values to input

Tags: jquery

This script adds the selected value from each select under #todoslosmodelos to the input #1471599855
How can I modify it so that it only adds the current selected values? Meaning if I change a selected value to another value then the previous selected value would be removed form the input so that it always reflects only the current selected values from all selects under #todoslosmodelos?

```js
var val = "";
var theval = $("#1471599855");

$("#todoslosmodelos select").change(function() {

  val = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
  if (val.length > 0) {
    //addVals = addVals + val1;
    theval.val(theval.val() + val + ", ");

  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset id="todoslosmodelos">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="checkbox" id="modeload-modelo-40"><input id="40" type="checkbox" value="40" />
      <div class="single-item">
        <div><label for="40"><img alt="" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1v3Tg16LptDiUDK6tMoPZvpTaztiuJOqR" /></label></div>

        <div><label for="40"><img alt="" data-lazy="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=18vU7K4MMZylkuS3hPTz1vNLQfTZthi5j" src="null" /></label></div>

        <div><label for="40"><img alt="" data-lazy="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1KSFpMlG5Nke_8q5D_MBzLnXzdGZLowru" src="null" /></label></div>

        <div><label for="40"><img alt="" data-lazy="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1YmPzIQ7n2p5s7TavwhTTJVGR8RXegeKL" src="null" /></label></div>

        <div><label for="40"><img alt="" data-lazy="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1G7eQhmSJpdRaV5HmVm-iVt8wXiloHqPO" src="null" /></label></div>
      </div>

      <div class="novisible" id="talles-modelo-40">
        <div class="select"><label for="hwA-qty-modelo-40">PARA SELECCIONAR TALLES PRIMERO MARC&Aacute; LA CANTIDAD DE PARES DE &quot;MODELO 40&quot;</label><br />
          <label>1 <input name="hwA-qty-modelo-40" type="radio" value="1" /></label> <label>2 <input name="hwA-qty-modelo-40" type="radio" value="2" /></label> <label>3 <input name="hwA-qty-modelo-40" type="radio" value="3" /></label></div>

        <fieldset class="fieldsetstalles" id="hwA-modelo-40-1">
          <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control talle">
              <option selected value="">-- Seleccione Talle --</option>
              <option value="35-modelo-40">35</option>
              <option value="36-modelo-40">36</option>
              <option value="37-modelo-40">37</option>
              <option value="38-modelo-40">38</option>
              <option value="39-modelo-40">39</option>
              <option value="40-modelo-40">40</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset class="fieldsetstalles" id="hwA-modelo-40-2">
          <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control talle">
              <option selected value="">-- Seleccione Talle --</option>
              <option value="35-modelo-40">35</option>
              <option value="36-modelo-40">36</option>
              <option value="37-modelo-40">37</option>
              <option value="38-modelo-40">38</option>
              <option value="39-modelo-40">39</option>
              <option value="40-modelo-40">40</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset class="fieldsetstalles" id="hwA-modelo-40-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control talle">
              <option selected value="">-- Seleccione Talle --</option>
              <option value="35-modelo-40">35</option>
              <option value="36-modelo-40">36</option>
              <option value="37-modelo-40">37</option>
              <option value="38-modelo-40">38</option>
              <option value="39-modelo-40">39</option>
              <option value="40-modelo-40">40</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox" id="modeload-modelo-39"><input id="39" type="checkbox" value="39" />
      <div class="single-item">
        <div><label for="39"><img alt="" data-lazy="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1rw9fI90Gp5z4gThKLVqMvaRWFUtpmAXD" src="null" /></label></div>

        <div><label for="39"><img alt="" data-lazy="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1D3rZKrVPHwy40CVGWX2g62i6gJ8xU0r_" src="null" /></label></div>

        <div><label for="39"><img alt="" data-lazy="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1Y16ldT1s7vy2892xUVmaZzSRVj1vTZYd" src="null" /></label></div>

        <div><label for="39"><img alt="" data-lazy="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1UDAn49FofPAQDL93r0ruScgbXk4qUoQ0" src="null" /></label></div>

        <div><label for="39"><img alt="" data-lazy="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1B7-M_ewJ3wUrrTTKH2covvCVxxkUOGUq" src="null" /></label></div>
      </div>

      <div class="novisible" id="talles-modelo-39">
        <div class="select"><label for="hwA-qty-modelo-39">PARA SELECCIONAR TALLES PRIMERO MARC&Aacute; LA CANTIDAD DE PARES DE &quot;MODELO 39&quot;</label><br />
          <label>1 <input name="hwA-qty-modelo-39" type="radio" value="1" /></label> <label>2 <input name="hwA-qty-modelo-39" type="radio" value="2" /></label> <label>3 <input name="hwA-qty-modelo-39" type="radio" value="3" /></label></div>

        <fieldset class="fieldsetstalles" id="hwA-modelo-39-1">
          <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control talle">
              <option selected value="">-- Seleccione Talle --</option>
              <option value="35-modelo-39">35</option>
              <option value="36-modelo-39">36</option>
              <option value="37-modelo-39">37</option>
              <option value="38-modelo-39">38</option>
              <option value="39-modelo-39">39</option>
              <option value="40-modelo-39">40</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset class="fieldsetstalles" id="hwA-modelo-39-2">
          <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control talle">
              <option selected value="">-- Seleccione Talle --</option>
              <option value="35-modelo-39">35</option>
              <option value="36-modelo-39">36</option>
              <option value="37-modelo-39">37</option>
              <option value="38-modelo-39">38</option>
              <option value="39-modelo-39">39</option>
              <option value="40-modelo-39">40</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset class="fieldsetstalles" id="hwA-modelo-39-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control talle">
              <option selected value="">-- Seleccione Talle --</option>
              <option value="35-modelo-39">35</option>
              <option value="36-modelo-39">36</option>
              <option value="37-modelo-39">37</option>
              <option value="38-modelo-39">38</option>
              <option value="39-modelo-39">39</option>
              <option value="40-modelo-39">40</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>


<fieldset>
  <legend for="1471599855"><br /> MODELOS/TALLES SELECCIONADOS:<br />
    <span style="font-size: 11px;">muestra los Modelos/Talles que seleccionaste arriba.</span></legend>

  <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" id="1471599855" name="entry.1471599855" readonly="readonly" type="text" /></div>
</fieldset>
```

FIDDLE including markup here:
http://jsfiddle.net/hejsz43y/2/

Comment: please share your markup as well

Comment: @NidhinJoseph http://jsfiddle.net/hejsz43y/2/

Comment: @sebas Please use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58143433/edit) tool and include the markup *in the question itself*. You can use the StackSnippet tool if you want a runnable snippet, similar to JSFiddle.

Comment: @TylerRoper its too big longer than limit. Please check markup as well as js here: http://jsfiddle.net/hejsz43y/2/

Comment: @sebas Your code is targeting *two* elements; you absolutely do not need all 600 lines of your HTML to create a simple demonstration.  Please include a [*minimal, reproducible example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that users don't have to navigate to an entirely different website to understand the question.

Comment: @TylerRoper added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep track of the previously selected value and remove it when the option is changed.

```
var val = "";
var theval = $("#1471599855");

$("#todoslosmodelos select").change(function(){
  val = $.each($(this).children("option:selected"), ()=> {
  var before_change = $(this).data('pre');
  let value = $(this).val()
  if(value.length>0) {
    if(before_change && before_change.length>0) {
        theval.val(theval.val().replace(before_change + ", ", "") + value + ", ");
    } else {
    theval.val(theval.val() + value + ", ");
    } 
  }
  if(value.length==0){
    theval.val(theval.val().replace(before_change + ", ", "")); 
  }
  $(this).data('pre', $(this).val());
  });
  console.log(theval.val())
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0ybfsLoj/

Comment: This almost does it but it didnt. When you select an option and then go back to "seleccionar talle" where value is "", it doesnt remove the previous selection from input

Comment: Edited the implementation, Try now.

Comment: there is one little mistake, when you change a selection to "seleccionar talle" but then u change it again to another value, the separattor gets lost ", " and so the values are stuck together, can u check it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe, this markup and the values of the select will remain like as you have shown in your code snippet. Your existing script fetch all the existing data from $("#1471599855") and append newly selected fields without checking if the values from that dropdown is already taken or not.

If I were you what I will do is on every change of select I would picked selected value and put it in "fieldsetstalles" with extra attribute and then loop through on it get selected data from there and put it into the input field or simply, every change of select I will pick latest selected values and put into input field.

EDIT: Here I've saved fiddle anonymously, I'm not sure it show you updated code for you or not. http://jsfiddle.net/3La6d4mj/

I'm trying here with later solution that I've mentioned.

```
var val = "";
var theval = $("#1471599855");

$("#todoslosmodelos select").change(function(){
var data = '';
  $(".fieldsetstalles select").each(function(){


    if( '' != $(this).children("option:selected").val() ) {
            data += $(this).children("option:selected").val() + ", ";
}
  });
  theval.val(data); 
});
```

This should be what you need I guess.

Comment: how to avoid adding value to input if value is blank?

Comment: @sebas Ahh.. I forget to put code. Please check I've edited the code.